# Setting index in MySql on a Varchar Column

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

In MySql, I have a UNION query which takes long for execution. 
The query looks like

```
(SELECT id, X, Y , date FROM TABLE WHERE date in (SELECT MIN(date) FROM TABLE WHERE flag = 0 AND id = ? AND date BETWEEN ? AND ?) and id = ? and flag=0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)

UNION 

(SELECT id, X, Y , date FROM TABLE WHERE date in (SELECT MAX(date) FROM TABLE WHERE flag = 0 AND id = ? AND date BETWEEN ? AND ?) and id = ? and flag = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

The question is for best performance of above query, what columns need to be indexed and why ?

```
id - type int
date - type datetime
flag - type tinyint(4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I indexed following
1. id
2. date
3. flag